# Convert Object holding arrays to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object which contain multiple arrays like in the following screenshot:

[image: Object Screenshot]

and I would like to convert it into this object:

```
{ "Manifacture": "Samsung", "Model": "Ipad 2" }
```

in order to use the data in bootstrap table.

When using `stringify`, I'm getting the following:

```
"{"Manifacture":[{"id":2,"name":"Samsung"}],"Model":[{"id":1,"name":"Ipad 2"}]"}"
```

which is different than what I need.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just process the object using plain javascript.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    obj[key] = obj[key][0].name
}

JSON.stringify(obj)
```